# How can i use RSA with Spring security at the same time?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, rsa

Hi i have struggled with remember me in login page in spring framework.

i need to add auto login feature into my team project and project has already used rsa, so when i login, it is automatically go to action="/useRSA"

i tried to make "Remember me" in my login.jsp and i have read that

add this kind code

```
<form name="frm" action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
```

Remember me

like this. i already set all required things for spring security and remember me.

but when i tried to login, always move to "/j_spring_security_check" just literally sent this address :'(

I can't remove action="/useRSA".

how can i use this security feature for login check?

Comment: What does `/useRSA` have to do with authentication or remember me cookies? Does `/useRSA` require you to load a private key or a client certificate into the form before posting that form? If not, I fail to see the benefit to use RSA here (you haven't actually described how it is implemented so I'm guessing a lot here; if you want your question answered, you should tell us more about that method).

Comment: Be more precise on which authentication scenario you want to create, which use of RSA do you want to do, and what do you really call RSA ? The algorithm, a framework, a key in a certificate, etc?